# Might calcium supplements be behind Granulomatosis With Polyangiitis (Wegener's)?

Tags: autoimmune-disease, calcium

Disclaimer: I have no formal medical or scientific education.

Abstract

My thesis is that the calcium created by man-made processes is not the correct [isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) to support the biological functions for which calcium is required and the granules of unprocessed calcium that appear in Granulomatosis are there because they are of the wrong isotope and end up destroying the ANCA.

The analysis

According to this article [calcium **isotopes** are what the body needs, not just the element, calcium](http://Calcium%20is%20the%20most%20abundant%20metal%20and%20the%20fifth-most%20abundant%20element%20in%20the%20human%20body.%20As%20electrolytes,%20calcium%20ions%20play%20a%20vital%20role%20in%20the%20physiological%20and%20biochemical%20processes%20of%20organisms%20and%20cells:%20in%20signal%20transduction%20pathways%20where%20they%20act%20as%20a%20second%20messenger;%20in%20neurotransmitter%20release%20from%20neurons;%20in%20contraction%20of%20all%20muscle%20cell%20types;%20as%20cofactors%20in%20many%20enzymes;%20and%20in%20fertilization.%20Calcium%20ions%20outside%20cells%20are%20important%20for%20maintaining%20the%20potential%20difference%20across%20excitable%20cell%20membranes%20as%20well%20as%20proper%20bone%20formation.). It must be the right isotope or the required reaction does not occur (emphases mine):

> ...Calcium is the most abundant **metal** and the fifth-most abundant element in the human body. As electrolytes, **calcium ions** play a vital role in the physiological and biochemical processes of organisms and cells: in signal transduction pathways where they act as a second messenger; in neurotransmitter release from neurons; in contraction of all muscle cell types; as cofactors in many enzymes; and in fertilization. **Calcium ions** outside cells are **important for maintaining the potential difference across excitable cell membranes as well as proper bone formation**...

How many different isotopes of calcium are there? These are the main ones:

[image: Main isotopes of calcium]

Now, I can't predict the actual odds of the industrial processes used to make this calcium resulting in the correct isotope by chance but it must be agreed that it is extremely unlikely. But even if they hit that particular lottery once, there are [multiple processes in use in different countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium#Occurrence_and_production) so it seems extremely unlikely that the suppliers are supplying the right isotope.

---

---

I have a family member with this disease. She is very health conscious and was taking calcium supplements when she received the diagnosis for Granulomatosis With Polyangiitis. She has continued to take the supplements and despite the buildup of these granules of calcium crystals in her cells her bones are quickly losing calcium.

Ironically, our mother's disease was attributed to overuse of talcum powder, which is from dolomite:

[image: Dolomite]

Dolomite has been found in the granules of patients (sorry, can't find the link yet):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolomite#/media/File:Dolomite_Luzenac.jpg

Comment: Could aluminum be the culprit?  Let's say she was taking calcium citrate and also taking say Mylanta?  Or say she was using dolomite and taking some citrate, say potassium citrate. She may absorb more of the aluminum. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2042654/

Comment: Lead. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/art.20534, anyway, it may be wise to drop the citrate form.

Comment: Aluminum induced pulmonary granulomatosis:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/730152/

Comment: I doubt your sister is taking dolomite (which can have impurities including aluminum) as a calcium source. But she could be taking calcium citrate. She could be getting aluminum from something. Speculative. I will remove some of these comments later.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I'm not aware of her having the side effects listed particularly but I'll have her check the labels. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding the study in the second comment:  In summary, this study suggests that several environmental exposures might be potential risk factors for development of Wegener's granulomatosis. These are worthy of further and more detailed consideration. It also suggests that a history of sinusitis (whether allergic, bacterial, or both...

Comment: I convinced my sister to stop taking the calcium supplements (by showing her this: https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/wellness-and-prevention/calcium-supplements-should-you-take-them ). Not long after a blood test showed that her iron, which had been dropping precipitously, remained stable. I have since convinced her that blackstrap molasses was a bioavailable source of calcium (which also was dropping with the supplements), iron and zinc and she has gone back to work and when I spoke to her she had just finished working out in her garden. I realize this is anecdotal, but hey...

Comment: My sister is still doing remarkably well. However, my research has moved in another direction. Wegener's rarely/never affects blacks. So... melatonin. It turns out that melatonin production is driven by the pineal gland. Whites have a seriously above average rate of calcification of the pineal gland! This is attributed to fluoride and artificial calcium supplements. We are currently experimenting with melatonin supplements.

Comment: "Granulomatosis with polyangiitis (GPA) is a systemic necrotizing vasculitis, which affects small- and medium-sized blood vessels and is often associated with cytoplasmic ANCA. GPA occurs in patients between 45 and 60 years old of both genders, and is rarely observed in blacks.... 
 "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25149391-granulomatosis-with-polyangiitis-wegener-clinical-aspects-and-treatment/?from_term=granulomatosis+polyangiitis&from_pos=1